# Printing with page-break-before: always. Top Margin on subsequent pages

Tags: html, css, printing

Bit of a strange one.

I have a script that generates a number of picking lists for a warehouse. At the top of the picking lists, I'm outputting the customers address. The location of this on the print out is important as the warehouse prints these out onto perforated sticky paper and need the addresses to fall within certain boundaries for address labels.

I have it all set up so that when they select 1 picking list to print, it falls exactly where it is needed. However, on subsequent pages there is a smaller margin at the top of the page (see image - the left is the first page... all subsequent pages are in the format of the right hand page)

[image]

The page body has padding:0 and margin:0

Each picking list is contained in a div and on pages >1 have page-break-before:always

```
<div style="page-break-before: always;">
    <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' style='width:600px; margin:35px 0 0 22px;'>
       ......
       <!--picking list output in here-->
       ......
    </table>
</div>
```

They are printing from IE8 but I am experiencing the same thing in firefox and chrome.

What could be causing the reduced spacing at the top of the subsequent pages (or the extra space at the top of the first page)?

Thanks